# AngularJS ngRequired directive and state of $invalid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use AngularJS Credit Card validation code frome https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards

When I have added an example code

```
<input type="text" ng-model="card.number" name="cardNumber" cc-number cc-eager-type />
<p ng-show="ccForm.cardNumber.$invalid && ccForm.cardNumber.$ccEagerType">
Looks like you're typing a {{paymentForm.cardNumber.$ccEagerType}} number!
</p>
<div ng-show="(ccForm.cardNumber.$invalid  && ccForm.cardNumber.$viewValue != null)">Card number is invalid</div>
```

to the demo code here http://embed.plnkr.co/uE47aZ/preview

I was able to type in letters into the cc-field without throwing error message.

Question is how I can display Invalid CC number message when the field is required but prevent when CC number was removed status for `ccForm.cardNumber.$invalid` will be still `true`

**UPDATE:**
I have moved code to have one massage for both cases

```
<div ng-show="(ccForm.cardNumber.$invalid  && ccForm.cardNumber.$ccEagerType) || (ccForm.cardNumber.$invalid &&  ccForm.cardNumber.$viewValue != '')">Card number is invalid</div>
```

it works to some point when the filed was touched but nothing was typed in there. In that case I displays both message - required and invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It is a temporary workaround for `ngRequired` directive case used in a combination with `cc-number`, `cc-cvc` or `cc-exp` and related to issues with the https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards code when the field was `$touched` but nothing was typed in that field. Acceptance criteria in that case is to display only Required message but not Invalid message (any value wasn't provided yet).

To have it resolved, without editing mine code, is to set initial value for mentioned above fields. Example below:

```
ng-init="card.number=''"
```

then to use it with a combination below to display proper message

```
<span ng-show="(form.input.$error.required || form.input.$error.parse) &&  form.input.$viewValue == ''">Required entry</span>
<span ng-show="form.input.$invalid &&  form.input.$viewValue != ''">Entry is invalid</span>
```

I think it will be good to have it mentioned somewhere in a documentation until it will be fixed permanently in the code.